# How to set corner radius value with CAShaperLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cornerradius

i drew a vertical line with UIBeizerPath and i need this line to have a corner radius with a value of 5. i tried to recall `[pathLayer setCornerRadius: 5];` but I do not get results ... Can you help me? how can I assign a corner radius value? this is the code I use

```
    // crea le barre del grafico e gli assegna l'altezza della label y corrispondente
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xPaddingFromYAxis +spaceBetweenBar *j, 200)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPaddingFromYAxis +spaceBetweenBar *j,  yLabelValue.center.y )];

    CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    pathLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    pathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 50;
    [pathLayer setCornerRadius:5];
    pathLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    [scroll.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set mask to bound as 'YES'.  `pathLayer.masksToBounds = YES;`

Try this and see:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xPaddingFromYAxis +spaceBetweenBar *j, 200)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPaddingFromYAxis +spaceBetweenBar *j,  yLabelValue.center.y )];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.bounds;
pathLayer.path = path.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
pathLayer.lineWidth = 50;
[pathLayer setCornerRadius:5];
pathLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
[scroll.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
```

Comment: I tried with maskToBound = YES but the line disappears, you can not see it anymore ... why?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot? With and without `pathLayer.masksToBounds`? It works for me.

Comment: Could I have misplaced the way I created the code? do you want me to show you everything in a pastebin link?

Comment: Update corner radius value from 5.0 to 0.5 (see result and gradually increase it....)

Comment: Can you share me sample (full) source code? what you've in your code. So I can solve it easily

Comment: if you think there are errors in the code can you tell me? sometimes i'm not sure of my code